# PHP 7.0.8 missing Curl constant

Tags: php, security, curl, https, libcurl

I installed my PHP 7.0.8 version from here: 
http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

From phpinfo:

```
PHP Version 7.0.8
```

Then I also installed the latest version CURL, as is show in phpinfo:

```
cURL Information    7.49.1
```

This page shows the new cURL option that has been added for 7.0.7:

```
i.e. CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

But when I run my code do like

```
echo CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY
```

its return as string, but not integer....

Or using in CURL:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY, "sha256//TeyzGG/8dvpuksAeSCb3tsvLEHbY6w9q63tXhOIf0Tg=");
```

It doesn't work either...

===== EDIT: Add PHP INFO

And here is my PHPinfo: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xdmx9i67rabcql/phpinfo%28%29.html?dl=0

Comment: Can you show the output of `phpinfo()` please

Comment: @ymas I just added the link to my phpinfo html.

Comment: Make sure to also update `php-common` so you get the latest cURL for 7.0.8.